# Does compose in Aurelia.js have an events?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm wander to know is there a way to bind to some callbacks at compose attribute is Aurelia.js.

I'm trying to do something like that

**view.html**

```
<a click.delegate="changeTab('first')">Tab 1</a> 
<a click.delegate="changeTab('second')">Tab 2</a> 
<a click.delegate="changeTab('third')">Tab 3</a>

<compose view-model.bind="tab"></compose>
```

At each tab I have same code at `attached` event

**first.js**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class First {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached() {
        $(this.element).find('code').each(function () {
            Prism.highlightElement($(this)[0]);
        });
    }
}
```

---

***The question is***

Does the `<compose>` have similar events I may bind on to it? I mean

**view.html**

```
<compose view-model.bind="tab" attached.bind="composeAttached()"></compose>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Aurelia way" of doing this would be:

```js
import {inject, customAttribute} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customAttribute('syntax-highlight')
@inject(Element)
export class SyntaxHighlight {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    Prism.highlightElement(this.element);
  }
}
```

```html
<pre><code syntax-highlight>...</code></pre>
```